# Angular: change the ng-model value of the cloned DOM element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am cloning the DOM element with the help of the `ng-template` Th clone is generating when I click at one dropdown all the clones behave same due to `ng-model` cloned.

```
<ng-template #clone>
<div class="mask1" *ngIf="question1 === true">
    <div class="">
        <div style="margin-left:15px">
            <div class="row margin-top-10">
                <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-xs-1  ">
                    <button mat-mini-fab class="oval">
                        1
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-xs-5 how-do-you-feel margin-top-10 ">
                    How do you feel?
                    <div class="line"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6  col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6 ">
                    <div class="col-xs-11">
                    <mat-radio-button class="pull-right" value="1"  *ngIf="questiontype === 'multiplechoice'">
                                                    <mat-form-field class="choices">
                                                        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="questiontype" [(value)]="questiontype" (change)="changeOptions(questiontype)" class="choices">
                                                            <mat-option value="paragraph">
                                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify choices "></span> Paragraph
                                                            </mat-option>
                                                            <mat-option value="multiplechoice">
                                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record choices"></span> Multiple choice
                                                            </mat-option>
                                                            <mat-option value="checkboxes">
                                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check choices"></span> Checkboxes
                                                            </mat-option>
                                                            <mat-option value="linearscale">
                                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal choices"></span> Linear scale
                                                            </mat-option>
                                                            <mat-option value="date">
                                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar choices"></span> Date
                                                            </mat-option>
                                                        </mat-select>
                                                    </mat-form-field>
                                                </mat-radio-button>

                                        <span assets/img/dublicate@3x.png 3x " class="dublicate " (click)="cloneTemplate() " >

        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

My TS file:

```
 // What to clone
@ViewChild('clone') template;

// Where to insert the cloned content
@ViewChild('container', {read:ViewContainerRef}) container;

 cloneTemplate(){

    const view = this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
    this.container.insert(view);

}
```

Sorry for the HTML part, but what I am trying to say is that can we change the behaviour of the cloned element.

I am thinking about to change the `ng-model` for cloned.

video  link of my project  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ND3IdZLTyvg&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Why are you trying to clone an element that's generated by Angular? Just generate it twice

Comment: And `<span assets/img/dublicate@3x.png 3x "` is clearly invalid markup

Comment: Have you tried checking out `view.context` ? https://angular.io/api/core/EmbeddedViewRef

Comment: i have  functionalities in my project that it should clone the dom element and html code was very big so i could not edit  @JeremyThille

Comment: no @AnteJablanAdamović